# Embed Excel Display in asp.net core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, office365, asp.net-core-5.0, excel-online

we would like to simulate an excel worksheet data input in an asp.net core application (windows authentication).

Is there a way (for demo pursposes) to embed the Excel (office 365) worksheet in a Asp.Net Core view?

Comment: You can use an IFRAME to display the sheet page inside your own

Comment: we would like to control the data then... I mean, read/update cells...